# Motion Editor Alternative in Flash Professional CC

Tags: flash, adobe

I've been working on a project that was originally made in Flash CS4.

I've got to the point where I want to start tweaking the speed of motion tweens and their placement.

Now as far as I understand there is no Motion Editor in Flash CC. After Googling for ages, people are saying to downgrade to Flash CS6, however since I only have Creative Cloud, that isn't a option.

In terms of motion in Flash, I can only see the Motion Presets, which are also very limiting in how you are able to modify them.

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For now, this looks promising.
http://nipunasthana.wordpress.com/2013/12/21/motion-help/

Maybe it will be integrated into Flash CC in the near future--*maybe* Adobe didn't mean it when they said the Motion Editor was being deprecated. I sure hope this guy pulls through. :)

---

**EDIT 2015: FLASH NOW HAS A MOTION EDITOR AGAIN**

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flash CS6 as a Creative Cloud member.  Go to https://creative.adobe.com/products/flash, and you will see a drop-down box where you can select either Flash CC or Flash CS6.  I've had to do this for After Effects which also lost some features in its CC release.

Answer (score 0):

You have to double click on motion span to open motion editor.
So simple - so hard to find ;)
https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/using/editing-motion-tween-using-motion.html

Comment: When this question was first asked, Adobe had temporarily removed Motion Editor :P